# Rails Functional Test - excluding method from setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, functional-testing

This should be simple but I can't find any examples.  I have standard functional tests in my rails 3 application (descending from ActionController::TestCase) that look like:

```
test "see if 1+1=2" do
....
end
```

and at the top I have a setup method:

```
setup do
  ......
end
```

How do I exclude a method? I.e.

```
setup :except => "see if 1+1=2" do
...
end
```

(above doesn't work obv)

Answer (score 0):

Use [shoulda](http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) and context blocks, that way you can put the tests using the setup in one context, and the tests not using them in another, or outside the other context block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about this too.  A workaround without installing and learning any new gems would be to define a private function within your test

```
test "see if 1+1=2" do
  setup_situation_1
  ...
end

test "see if 1 * 1 = 1" do
  setup_situation_1
  ..
end

test "see if 1/1 = 1" do
  # no setup here
  ...
end

...

private
def setup_situation_1
  ...
end
```

This is the DRY-est approach I can think of without installing/learning a new gem--which may be a preferable solution for some people, especially those new to rails.  However, I can't find the documentation on this setup/do method--an "except" clause for setup/do would certainly be DRY-er.